# Checking the data in a dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, join, pyspark

I have a dataset `df_1` that looks like this:

```
my_id        scope         feat_1     feat_2    value_1    value_2     value_3          date
23784    some_code          Three          A         30         60          60    2022-01-01
23794    some_code          Seven          B         60         40          20    2022-01-01
23774    some_cod1          Three          A         90         40          60    2022-01-02
22784    some_cod1          Three          C         30         10          60    2022-01-01
23564    some_cod2           Four          A         20         40          20    2022-01-05
20784    some_cod3           Five          A         10         70          40    2022-02-08
```

I need to perform a simple calculation on it, but since it updates quite often, I want to make sure that all the data is there. For that, I have the following guide `df_2`. `version` is always increasing and tells me when the newest update happened and I **only care about the maximum `version` for a certain scope and date**.

```
my_id        scope         feat_1     feat_2                   date     version
23784    some_code          Three          A             2022-01-01         600
23794    some_code          Seven          B             2022-01-01         600   
23774    some_cod1          Three          A             2022-01-02         600       
22784    some_cod1          Three          C             2022-01-01         650
23564    some_cod2           Four          A             2022-01-05         650
20784    some_cod3           Five          A             2022-02-08         700
20744    some_cod2           Five          A             2022-01-05         700
20745    some_cod2           Four          C             2022-01-05         700
```

**How do I look at `df_2`, group by `scope` and `date` and get the maximum `version`, and then see if all `my_id`s are present in `df_1` for this version?**

What I did was to perform a left anti-join to see which `my_id`s are present in `df_2` but not in `df_1`, in the whole dataset. However, I only care about the highest `version` for a `scope` and `date`. How can I do this? I cannot just `df_2.groupBy("scope", "date").max("version")` and then do the left anti-join, can I?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pyspark.sql.Window` to do this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as F, Window

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("scope", "date")

# Only retain rows with the max version after grouping by scope and date. 
df2_my_id = (
    df2.withColumn("max_version", F.max("version").over(windowSpec))
    .filter(F.col("max_version")==F.col("version"))
    .select("my_id")
)

df2_my_id.show()

+-----+
|my_id|
+-----+
|22784|
|23774|
|20744|
|20745|
|20784|
|23784|
|23794|
+-----+
```

Then use [`pyspark.sql.DataFrame.subtract`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.subtract.html) to find out all the IDs in `df2` but not in `df1`.

```py
df2_my_id.subtract(df1.select("my_id")).show()

+-----+
|my_id|
+-----+
|20744|
|20745|
+-----+
```

If this count is greater than 0 that means there are some IDs in `df2` that are not present in `df1`.

```py
df2_my_id.subtract(df1.select("my_id")).count() > 0 # Returns True in this case
```